# HibernateTemplate.find() throws NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception

We're getting an exception of:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl3L#gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl3LId@78c0fb45]
```

The problem is that my understanding of the many posts on this exception is that they are all save or update related.  This shouldn't happen as the result of a find() right?

We're not really understanding how it can be illegal to query the same database row twice in the same session as part of two different find() calls.  I mean, that's what L1 cache is FOR, right?

(update)
Here's the ID class.  It does override the equals and update.  Not sure why.  It was written by someone else.

```
public class OrgLvl3LId implements java.io.Serializable {

private String structureCd;
private String orgLvl1Cd;
private String orgLvl2Cd;
private String orgLvl3Cd;

public OrgLvl3LId() {
}

public OrgLvl3LId(String structureCd, String orgLvl1Cd, String orgLvl2Cd,
        String orgLvl3Cd) {
    this.structureCd = structureCd;
    this.orgLvl1Cd = orgLvl1Cd;
    this.orgLvl2Cd = orgLvl2Cd;
    this.orgLvl3Cd = orgLvl3Cd;
}

public String getStructureCd() {
    return this.structureCd;
}

public void setStructureCd(String structureCd) {
    this.structureCd = structureCd;
}

public String getOrgLvl1Cd() {
    return this.orgLvl1Cd;
}

public void setOrgLvl1Cd(String orgLvl1Cd) {
    this.orgLvl1Cd = orgLvl1Cd;
}

public String getOrgLvl2Cd() {
    return this.orgLvl2Cd;
}

public void setOrgLvl2Cd(String orgLvl2Cd) {
    this.orgLvl2Cd = orgLvl2Cd;
}

public String getOrgLvl3Cd() {
    return this.orgLvl3Cd;
}

public void setOrgLvl3Cd(String orgLvl3Cd) {
    this.orgLvl3Cd = orgLvl3Cd;
}

public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if ((this == other))
        return true;
    if ((other == null))
        return false;
    if (!(other instanceof OrgLvl3LId))
        return false;
    OrgLvl3LId castOther = (OrgLvl3LId) other;

    return ((this.getStructureCd() == castOther.getStructureCd()) || (this
            .getStructureCd() != null
            && castOther.getStructureCd() != null && this.getStructureCd()
            .equals(castOther.getStructureCd())))
            && ((this.getOrgLvl1Cd() == castOther.getOrgLvl1Cd()) || (this
                    .getOrgLvl1Cd() != null
                    && castOther.getOrgLvl1Cd() != null && this
                    .getOrgLvl1Cd().equals(castOther.getOrgLvl1Cd())))
            && ((this.getOrgLvl2Cd() == castOther.getOrgLvl2Cd()) || (this
                    .getOrgLvl2Cd() != null
                    && castOther.getOrgLvl2Cd() != null && this
                    .getOrgLvl2Cd().equals(castOther.getOrgLvl2Cd())))
            && ((this.getOrgLvl3Cd() == castOther.getOrgLvl3Cd()) || (this
                    .getOrgLvl3Cd() != null
                    && castOther.getOrgLvl3Cd() != null && this
                    .getOrgLvl3Cd().equals(castOther.getOrgLvl3Cd())));
}

public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;

    result = 37
            * result
            + (getStructureCd() == null ? 0 : this.getStructureCd()
                    .hashCode());
    result = 37 * result
            + (getOrgLvl1Cd() == null ? 0 : this.getOrgLvl1Cd().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result
            + (getOrgLvl2Cd() == null ? 0 : this.getOrgLvl2Cd().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result
            + (getOrgLvl3Cd() == null ? 0 : this.getOrgLvl3Cd().hashCode());
    return result;
}

}
```

(update)
Snippet from the hmm.xml.  You can see the composite-id definition.

```
    <composite-id name="id" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl3LId">
        <key-property name="structureCd" type="string">
            <column name="STRUCTURE_CD" length="2" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="orgLvl1Cd" type="string">
            <column name="ORG_LVL1_CD" length="5" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="orgLvl2Cd" type="string">
            <column name="ORG_LVL2_CD" length="6" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="orgLvl3Cd" type="string">
            <column name="ORG_LVL3_CD" length="12" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

Comment: Show us the code of the entity and its ID. Maybe it has to do with their equals/hashCode implementations.

Comment: @JBNizet Here's the ID class.  this was all written by someone before my time.  I am not sure why he overrode the equals and hashCode, but you are right that he did.

Comment: @JBNizet - updated body of question with ID class.  The entityt does not override equals or hashCode.

Comment: The implementation seems fine. It's mandatory to properly define equals and hashCode on an entity ID. That's why he did it. Do you have a PK constraint on this set of 4 columns? Are you sure the table doesn't contain duplicates?

Comment: @JBNizet - Table does not have dupes on those 4 columns.  They are the keys in DB2.  hbm.xml is about to be appended to the orginal question.

Comment: @JBNizet I am wondering if the fact that we have a OpenSessionInViewFilter on this app might be involved?

Comment: I have the same problem, and just to add some more information, my query is a simple `select count(*) from MyEntity`!!! Can't understand why this is happening with a simple `find()`.