# NonUniqueObjectException from cached object

Tags: hibernate

I asked a related question a couple days ago that didn't get resolved, and now I have new info.  That question was ([HibernateTemplate.find() throws NonUniqueObjectException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730234/hibernatetemplate-find-throws-nonuniqueobjectexception)).

What I have discovered through massive overuse of printf debugging is that based on watching identityHashCodes, object 1 (whose natural keys are a composite of 4 fields) gets created near logon, and cached in the session because it is information about the logged in user.

A few requests later, a page pulls this object from the session, and uses it and some of the data attached to it to make some decisions and filter some lists by office assignments.  But the same natural key record was loaded earlier this session as object 2.

Now, I don't really see how Hibernate became aware of object 1 again, given that it was created a few sessions ago, nor do I see anything obvious in the code that works with object 1 like a merge or save or update on that object.  Yet, in the same milisecond that Hibernate throws a NonUniqueObjectException, hibernate called the overridden hashCode method on this object (which can be seen in the previous post).

So my question is, how might Hibernate have become aware of this object 1?  It knows about object 2 of course, it instantiated it in the current session, but object 1 was created several sessions ago.  Hibernate shouldn't be able to reconnect to this object spontaneously.  I though I had to merge() to reconnect.  But I don't see that in the code.  Would it be enough for some method to have used this object as a parameter or some other use?